# How can I change the style of a specific CCK field?

Tags: entities

I need to change the position to fields of content types. How can I modify the style of a specific field?

When I check the code for knowing the class, I see this:

```
<input id="edit-field-first-name-0-value" class="form-text text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="field_first_name[0][value]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can review the style in the source code, detecting the 'id' of the specific field.

for example add this rule (according the specific id):

```
#edit-field-color-value {
color:#00FF00;
}
```

Comment: remember that the field and his label has a DIV around they, so you can add a CSS, according the ID of this DIV, to control the field and the label.